# Geocoder search by miles and address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding, google-geocoder, geocode

I'm following this example http://asciicasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder for geocoding. Anyone got any idea how can i pass miles dynamically instead of giving static nearby 10 miles? So it will have two search boxes one for entering miles another for entering address. Thanks

controller.rb

```
def index  
  if params[:search].present?  
    @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 50, ↵  
      :order => :distance)  
  else  
    @locations = Location.all  
  end  
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% title "Locations" %>  

<%= form_tag locations_path, :method => :get do %>  
  <p>  
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>  
    <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an extra param to `show` view and apply it:

```
<% for location in @location.nearbys(params[:nearbys].to_i) %> // do not forget check if params[:nearbys] exists and it's an integer
```

Update all links to the `show` view:

```
<li><%= link_to location.address, location_path(location, nearby: 15) %> ↵  
(<%= location.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
```